# Drupal Commerce - PayPal Instant Payment Notification Warning

Tags: drupal, paypal, drupal-7, drupal-commerce

After a few days we always get this email from paypal when someone is paying with paypal on our onlineshop:

```
Please check your server that handles PayPal Instant Payment
Notifications (IPN). IPNs sent to the following URL(s) are failing:

[OUR_SHOP_URL]/commerce_paypal/ipn/paypal_wps%7Ccommerce_paymen
t_paypal_wps

If you do not recognize this URL, you may be using a service provider
that is using IPN on your behalf. Please contact your service provider
with the above information. If this problem continues, IPNs may be
disabled for your account.

Thank you for your prompt attention to this issue.


Sincerely,
PayPal
```

We are using Drupal Commerce on Drupal 7. The "funny" thing is: Sometimes this error appear, sometimes not. When this error appear the Drupal-Commerce can not set the Payment status to "Completed" so it costs a lot of time to do this manually ...

I found a "solution" for this here but the *.patch does not removed the problem: https://www.drupal.org/node/1055390

Any other solutions ? :/

**Edit:**

When take a look at the drupal recent log messages I can find the error which was tracked.

Here's the information I get:

```
Type        commerce_paypal
Date        Thursday, October 9, 2014 - 13:15
User        Anonymous (not verified)
Location    [URL]/commerce_paypal/ipn/paypal_wps%7Ccommerce_payment_paypal_wps
Referrer    
Message     IPN URL accessed with no POST data submitted.
Severity    warning
Hostname    173.0.81.1
Operations
```

**Edit 2:**

We found smth ... We have HTTPS. I jsut treid to use the HTTP Url. And ... this works fine. But we want to be at HTTPS isntead of HTTP. But maybe it will help you whats happened here ?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be an issue with Paypal itself - a user noted that sometimes the Paypal callback is encoded, thus pipe characters ("|") get encoded to "%7C". That user has described your problem - it's very hard to debug this issue, as it only occurs sometimes.

Here is a link to the issue, along with a small patch:

https://www.drupal.org/node/1055390#comment-7436538

This issue occurs on Paypal itself, although I am wondering why this patch hasn't been included in  drupal commerce itself...

Comment: I knew this problem before and fixed it - thanks :) But in our issue its not a Drupal problem I think ... its a HTTPS problem. When its HTTPS the problem occures - if not there is no problem and I have problems to understand why this happens ...

Answer (score 0):

You need to check your web server log files to see exactly what error is happening on the failures.  You'll be able to see the PHP error that you would typically see on screen when something is failing like that.

That will give you direction on what is going wrong and what you might need to do to fix it.

Another thing you could do is replicate the IPN that failed yourself and POST it directly to your IPN listener in a browser so that you can see the result on screen. This can help with troubleshooting and debugging.  Just create an HTML form with the action set to your IPN URL and then add a bunch of hidden fields that match the names/values you got in an order that failed.  That would trigger the same error so you can see it.

Comment: When I take a look to the recent log messages in my admin menu I get this error from the module in the list: IPN URL accessed with no POST data submitted.